# How to use over partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table:

```
ID  BS  time
1   1   14:10:00
1   1   14:10:05
1   1   15:04:03
1   2   16:18:05
1   2   17:00:09
1   3   18:33:50
1   1   19:03:14
1   1   19:10:23
```

and except:

```
ID  BS  start_time  end_time
1   1   14:10:00    16:18:05
1   2   16:18:05    18:33:50
1   3   18:33:50    19:03:14
1   1   19:03:14    19:10:23
```

I try use lead, but i don't know, how to resolve problem, when BS is repeat after is end

```
SELECT id,bs,time,--min(time) time_start,
lead(time,1) over (partition by id order by time) next_time,
FROM `sage-facet-114619.Temp_data.temp_table`
order by id,time
```

After that I think about group by after this, but I have problem with same BS's

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag because the syntax looks like BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and actually returns expected result - which is not a case with other two answers)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, bs, 
  MIN(time) AS start_time,
  MAX(IFNULL(end_time, time)) AS end_time
FROM (
  SELECT id, bs, time, end_time,
    COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      LEAD(time) OVER win AS end_time,
      bs != LAG(bs) OVER win AS flag
    FROM `sage-facet-114619.Temp_data.temp_table`
    WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time)
  )
)
GROUP BY id, bs, grp
```

If applied to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  bs  start_time  end_time     
1   1   1   14:10:00    16:18:05     
2   1   2   16:18:05    18:33:50     
3   1   3   18:33:50    19:03:14     
4   1   1   19:03:14    19:10:23
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The idfference of row numbers is one solution:

```
select id, min(time) as start_time,
       lead(min(time)) over (partition by id order by min(time)) as end_time
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partiton by id order by time) as seqnum_2
      from `sage-facet-114619.Temp_data.temp_table` t
      t
group by id, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Another solution in this case is `lag()`:

```
select id, time as start_time,
       lead(time) over (partition by id order by time) as end_time
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (order by time) as prev_id
      from `sage-facet-114619.Temp_data.temp_table` t
      t
where prev_id is null or prev_id <> id
```

Comment: Gordon, I'm not the one.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed a few oversights in Gordon's query. As I have not used BigQuery myself I can't speak to it's "standard" syntax or features but I trust that it is reliable outside of the relatively minor changes I made.

```
select
    id, bs, min(time) as start_time,
    coalesce(
        lead(min(time)) over (partition by id order by min(time)),
        max(time) -- corrected: max() rather than min()
    ) as end_time
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
        row_number() over (partition by id, bs order by time) as seqnum_2
    from t
    ) t
group by id, bs, seqnum - seqnum_2;
```

Please compare results (running against SQL Server): https://rextester.com/WCSL25882